# Why do websites not allow periods and the start and end of usernames?

Tags: web

I have seen several websites (Google, Yahoo, etc) that allow periods in usernames (or emails) but not at the start or end of it.

Why would there be such a restriction?

Comment: I don't see any technical reason. But you might consider asking those websites.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bundle of RFCs listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Local_part), specifying the standard for email local part. Those does not permit dots at start/end positions.

In fact, once your email provider will not reject sending an email with dots in front, Google will accept it, since she simply ignores dots in local part. Try it youself, send an email to

```
.yourname@google.com
```

—and you’ll receive it successfully.